# Which quantum computing programming language should I learn?

Tags: programming

Which quantum computing programming language should I learn? What are the benefits of said language? As of Wikipedia, there's quite a bit to choose from.

I'm looking to develop end-user applications (when quantum computers become end-user ready).

Answer (score 4):

If you like Python and want to run jobs on a real device, your options are [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/), [ProjectQ](https://projectq.ch/) or [Forest](https://www.rigetti.com/forest).

If you like Python and are happy to wait for access to a real device, you could additionally go for [Cirq](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/master/README.rst). In this case, you might also want to look into the features of the simulators provided by all the Python frameworks, to find the one that best suits your intended use cases.

All the Python frameworks use the same basic way of building up quantum circuits by laying down simple quantum gates. They differ in their fancy features. Since I work on Qiskit, I am most familiar with its fancy features. But the fancy features of the others may suit you better. It all depends on what you want to do. But your decision on which to learn is not irreversible: it should be quite easy to learn with one and then use that same experience in using the rest.

If you are familiar with Visual Studio, and especially if you work in C#, it may be that [Q#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/?view=qsharp-preview) would be easiest for you. I am not a Visual Studio kind of person, so I have no experience with this myself.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to first learn [Q-sharp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/?view=qsharp-preview) if you want to quickly get into quantum computing programming, otherwise play with existing libraries and framework like [Qiskit framework](https://qiskit.org/), [Qutip python](http://qutip.org/) library or [QETLAB matlab](http://www.qetlab.com/Main_Page) toolbox for feeling entanglement.

There is also a quantum computing [interactive playground](http://www.quantumplayground.net/#/home) by Google.

Answer (score 3):

[Q-sharp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/?view=qsharp-preview) is a nice starting point.

Also I would suggest some general purpose mathematical language.
[Julia](https://julialang.org/) is really awesome.