# IBM qiskit vs Microsoft QDK

Tags: programming, qiskit, q#

I am new to both IBM Qiskit and Microsoft QDK. I wish to understand which framework would be best suited for someone new to this field. I am lookig for the pros and cons of both frameworks.

Comment: This is a very subjective matter, and depends heavily on your own background and preferences. Also, why only Qiskit and Microsoft QDK? There's also Google Cirq, Rigetti Forest, ProjectQ, and other frameworks each of which has strengths and weaknesses depending on your specific needs.

Comment: I would recommend looking at James Wootton's answer to this similar question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5586/which-quantum-computing-programming-language-should-i-learn/